# Is there a Python function to compute minimal L2 norm between 2 matrices up to column permutation?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, permutation, metrics

I have two sets of column vectors X = (X_1 ... X_n), Y = (Y_1 ... Y_n) of same shape.

I would like to compute something like this:

[image: this]

i.e the minimal L2 norm between X and Y up to column permutation. Is it possible to do it in less than O(n!)? Is it already implemented in Numpy for instance? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice what the OP is asking for is not a regular L2 norm.

Comment: Are you sure you understood the question? It's not just a l2 norm it's a bit more specific than this. I don't find anything on Google, probably because I don't know how such a norm is called.

Comment: @Patrice You're right. I missed the difference in what you are calculating from the regular L2 norm. Still, you didn't indicate what you did find. [This `norm()` function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) looks promising. Does it not support what you are asking for? Did you read this documentation before asking here?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. The norm function is fine. OP is asking if there's a faster way to solve the minimization than O(n!) time, which gets prohibitive pretty fast

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes I looked at it and it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: So I think you can do this much faster if you're willing to sacrifice some memory. Looks like O(n^2), maybe O(n^3).

Comment: @MadPhysicist I feel like that too, but I really wouldn't know how to program it from scratch... I hope someone already did

Comment: Just so we're clear, the squared norm of two matrices is just the sum of the squares of all the elements, yes?

Comment: @Patrice. It's a graph problem in disguise (everything seems to be). I think I can bake a solution here with a bit of time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist well yes, and the X_i and Y_i are all column vectors so it's really the usual norm

Comment: @MadPhysicist that would be really nice of you but I'm surprised that it doesn't already exist in Numpy, or some obscure GitHub

Comment: @Patrice. What is the usecase? Perhaps that would help you find an implementation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm doing research on an obscure unsupervised method (Mapper) and I think I'm the first one to have the idea to use such a metric in the domain. I'm still looking for implementations in various research papers though

Comment: @MadPhysicist lol I'm not sure I'll be publishing anything with that but if I do I'll cite you for sure :) Now I'm trying to use Persistent Homology-based distances on my case (bottleneck distance between Alpha/Rips-complexes), I'll see what works best.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I edited the equation that was false, it's better written that way. Sorry.

Comment: Now you're adding up square-roots. I think the original formulation was better.

Comment: Fixed it, hope for the last time lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply
[scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html#scipy-optimize-linear-sum-assignment)
to the matrix A where A<sub>ij</sub> = ‖X<sub>i</sub> − Y<sub>j</sub>‖.

Comment: Awww. I was working on a home-baked solution with np.einsum and networkx. Excellent find :)

Comment: Wow really nice I wouldn't have found it by myself... Thank you very much to both of you!!!